# For Sun Grid Engine qsub, can you let the job notify multiple email addresses?

Tags: bash, qsub

I have been using the qsub system for a while now, but the first time I have encountered some problems: Is there a way to send multiple emails to two or more emails?

Here is my script header:

```
#!/bin/bash

#PBS -V
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=20
#PBS -l walltime=12:00:00
#PBS -M email1@school.edu,email2@gmail.com
#PBS -N Model_sim
```

I have tried the following methods:

1. I have searched online for a while for if I can do something at `-M` command, I have seen only one use here: http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html. However, it is not really working when I put my two emails like he did on the end of the page.
2. Also, I have tried the Bash tricks, but it seems like I can't insert any Bash lists after `#PBS -M` flag, or it shows me the syntax error.

If anyone knows anything regarding to this case, thank you to sharing the knowledge! Any suggestions would also recommanded!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually pretty easy, using `;` instead of `,`:

```
#PBS -M email1@school.edu;email2@gmail.com
```